# Sql server 2008 - performance tuning features for insert large amount of data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, performance

I have to insert large amount of data into a table. Does sqlserver 2008(compared to 2005) has any new features to increase the performance in this case ?

Comment: "I have to insert large amount of data into a table." - perhaps you would like to explain how you intend doing that; there are quite a few ways...

Comment: I am inserting using a stored procedure, in which I have insert  Select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is feasible for your problem, but if you can I would really try to develop this in code.

I had a similar question for a big project in the past, that needed to import 15 years worth of production data into a new schema (in SQL Server 2005.)
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy was by far the fastest option.

If you do go this way, I suggest doing inserts in lots of roughly 1 GB at a time, then manually calling the .NET GC to free up your table in memory. I was forced to do both of these things to not run into memory errors (32 bit system, though.)

Edit - Pseudocode for my solutiong was something like:

```
Table dataToInsert = new Table();
var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from old database");
DataReader dataFromOldSystem = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
foreach (DataRow oldRow in dataFromOldSystem.Tables[0])
{
// I had to modify/transpose the row from the old table in some way
DataRow newRow = new DataRow(oldRow.GetInt(0), oldRow.GetDateTime(1), oldRow.GetInt(2));
dataToInsert.AddRow(newRow);

newRow = new DataRow(oldRow.GetInt(0), oldRow.GetDateTime(1), oldRow.GetInt(3));
dataToInsert.AddRow(newRow);

newRow = new DataRow(oldRow.GetInt(0), oldRow.GetDateTime(1), oldRow.GetInt(4));
dataToInsert.AddRow(newRow);

// check if the number of rows is over some magic number that is below the memory limit
// you can check the private bytes in use by your app to help guess this number
if (dataToInsert.Rows.Count > 1000000)
{
SqlBulkCopy bulkCopier = new BulkCopy(blah);
bulkCopier.Execute();

dataToInsert = null;
GC.Finalize();
GC.Free;

dataToInsert = new Table();
}
}
```

Comment: You mean..call SQL bulk Copy in a loop and call GC to free ? If so how can I specify size of bulk copy as 1 GB. Do you have any sample code for same ?

Comment: I'm afraid I've moved jobs since then, so don't have sample code. In my case, I used trial and error and some educated guesses to do it.

Comment: I've added some pseudocode which is the basic idea behind the app I developed.

Comment: @Coxy " I was forced to do both of these things to not run into memory errors (32 bit system, though.)" If you do not use DataTables instead an IDataReader you do not run into these memory problems.

Answer (score 4):

SQL Server 2008 contains the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) TSQL statement which can speed up certain types of combined INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE operations.

If you are intending to perform through code, I would suggest using the [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx) class (but also present in SQL Server 2005).

Comment: I am not doing it through code. But is it like SqlBulkCopy fatser than normar database insert ??? If so, how fast it is???

Comment: Check The Data Loading Performance Guide http://bit.ly/9Due9T, SqlBulkCopy Class itself http://bit.ly/8Xxu2R and High performance bulk loading to SQL Server using SqlBulkCopy http://bit.ly/a9KZ2l if you still concerned. But if you do with TSQL then go MERGE